# Parameters to check before storing data on cloud

Tags: privacy, webserver, cloud-computing, cloud-storage

I want suggestions regarding the storing/securing my data on cloud.

I want to upload my data on cloud, so it will be safe and can be accessible from anywhere.

I have around 15 GB of data which I want to store it on cloud.

Can I use Google Drive (for Free) for this purpose ?

Is there any security issues if I use the Google drive for it ?

It will be nice, if I get list of companies which also provide this service at low price.

I also want to know which parameters I should check, before using cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

**PART 1 (example)**

Let's categorize your data as TOP SECRET , Classified and normal data.

- If you would want to store TOP SECRET data in cloud, I would suggest
  **NOT** to. Remember that in the moment you upload something online, you
  are not the only one who have access to it. But if you really have
  to, than it would be a good practice to encrypt your data before
  uploading it, because remember:

  **IF YOUR SERVICE PROVIDER ENCRYPTS YOUR DATA, THE SERVICE PROVIDER CAN
  DECRYPT YOUR DATA**
- If you would want to store Classified data, you must be sure you are
  storing the data in a trustworthy cloud service with good reputation.
  [Here](http://www.toptenreviews.com/services/web-hosting/best-cloud-services/) you have a study on the best cloud services.
- If you would want to store normal data, then the common services like
  Google Drive, Dropbox, One Drive are OK.

---

**PART 2**

In a general point of view you should know this things:

- Make sure the cloud vendor is up-to-date on data center and industry
  certifications.
- Pick a provider that suits your needs. Some providers are specialized
  in specific data types.
- Take a look at bandwidth limitations (if you store business
  data). If you are going to be using cloud as part of a backup
  strategy, you need to understand the bandwidth limitations both for
  the initial backup of a large amount of data, as well as what will
  happen should you need to restore a large amount of data.
- Make sure data is encrypted.
- Carefully read the provider's SLA.
- Know how much the cloud will actually cost you.
- Make sure you can recover/restore your data in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud is inherently insecure, so be skeptical with where ever you choose to upload your data. Depending on what kind of information you're uploading Google Drive would work, however I'd think twice before uploading sensitive info. If you're trying to *truly* store and *secure* your data on the cloud then you can look at services such as SpiderOak or Tresorit, both are not free however well worth it.